# About MpMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

Hi Everyone Gud Evening

I have taken a view on which i had to play the video, the video is being played Perfectly, but  very rarely i the video is not being appeared on the view, at that time i got a warning in the console like

WARNING: under normal conditions, _fillInQueueWithExtraSpace:ignoreExistingItems: should not be re-entered.

Could some one help me to sort out this problem

Thank  You Everyone

I have 2  UIView's in being displayed on the same view, In one view when i start drawing the movieplayer gets started in the bottomProgressView , in the viewcontroller in viewdidload the code is like this

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"progres" ofType:@"mp4"];
    timeCompletedCnlr = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]] ;
    [timeCompletedCnlr.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,468, 600, 50)]; 
    [timeCompletedCnlr setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [bottomProgressView addSubview:timeCompletedCnlr.view];
}
```

When i touch the  view that is being to drawn  then the below method is called.

```
     - (void)removeGivenWord
{
    [bottomToolBar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:bottomProgressView];

    [timeCompletedCnlr play];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(helpVideoFinished:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification     
                                               object:timeCompletedCnlr];

    UIButton *doneBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneBtn.frame = CGRectMake(601, 940, 167, 43);
    [doneBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:doneBtn];
```

}

the view on which the video is placed also contains the done button too..

```
    - (void)doneButtonClicked {       
[timeCompletedCnlr stop];       
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(helpVideoFinished:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                           object:timeCompletedCnlr];
```

}

```
     - (void) helpVideoFinished:(NSNotification*) aNotification {     
MPMoviePlayerController *player1 = [aNotification object];     
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self 
                                               name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                             object:player1];     
[smoothLineView completed5Sec];     
NSLog(@"5sec called");     
NSError *error = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];     
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Did finish with error: %@", error);
}
```

}

My Problem is the video sometimes it appears and sometime it doesn't come,

Comment: can you be more specific? Show us some code when you are calling the video.

Comment: @ AIbrahimZ: I have added the code here, i have edited could u kindly check it once.

Comment: That seems to be a cocos2d warning - did you forget to add that tag to your question or am I wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Got the message "WARNING: under normal conditions, _fillInQueueWithExtraSpace:.." and MPMoviePlayer rotation not work in iPad IOS 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806826/got-the-message-warning-under-normal-conditions-fillinqueuewithextraspace)

Comment: @Till : Hey Nope its not the duplicate of that, and no where in my project i am using cocos2d.

Comment: @Till - May be it is duplicate.... But where is the answer..... ? Nobody didn't give it yet. All questions are without any single answer.